# How can I run an external command and capture its output in Perl?

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr

I'm new to Perl and want to know of a way to run an external command (call it `prg`) in the following scenarios:

1. Run `prg`, get its `stdout` only.
2. Run `prg`, get its `stderr` only.
3. Run `prg`, get its `stdout` and `stderr`, separately.

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and spend some time on perldoc.perl.org -- for starters the "Tutorials" and "FAQs" areas. Also run this to familiarize yourself with Perl's system for accessing help info on the command-line: `perldoc --help`. The answer to your specific question could have been found directly by command-line searches such as these: `perldoc -q capture` or `perldoc -q external`.

Comment: You may want to look into `qx`, it might have ways to separate the streams and is easy to run e.g. `qx("command");`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the backtics to execute your external program and capture its `stdout` and `stderr`.

By default the backticks discard the `stderr` and return only the `stdout` of the external program.So

```
$output = `cmd`;
```

Will capture the `stdout` of the program cmd and discard `stderr`.

To capture only `stderr` you can use the shell's file descriptors as:

```
$output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
```

To capture both `stdout` and `stderr` you can do:

```
$output = `cmd 2>&1`;
```

Using the above you'll not be able to differenciate `stderr` from `stdout`. To separte `stdout` from `stderr` can redirect both to a separate file and read the files:

```
`cmd 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`;
```

Comment: Another way to read stdout and stderr separately, without using temporary files, is to use IPC::Open3.

Comment: Every time backticks are used, a kitten dies.  In shell, use $().  In perl, use qx.

Comment: Thanks for that, I killed 20 kittens before I used qx ;)

Comment: The second solution `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null` kills both stdout and stderr. Somehow the shell doesn't identify that the two redirections are separate!!

Comment: How do you pass arguments to `cmd` with backticks, ensuring proper escaping?

Comment: Fails: `perl -e 'my $f = ".../a  b"; print(qx/file $f/);'`. Succeeds: `perl -e 'use IPC::Open2; my $f = ".../a  b"; open2(my $out, my $in, "file", $f); print(readline($out))'`

Comment: It is worth adding that the command return code [is stored at `$?`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#$?), in case you want to peek at it before making use of the command output.

Comment: @L__ In Bash 4.3.48 `2>&1 1>/dev/null` works correctly (stderr goes to terminal, stdout is discarded).

Comment: `\`cmd 1>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt\`;` is a non-Perl solution, and using fixed filenames is probably a bad idea security-wise.

Answer (score 15):

In most cases you can use the [`qx//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) operator (or backticks). It interpolates strings and executes them with the shell, so you can use redirections.

- To capture a command's STDOUT (STDERR is unaffected):

  ```
  $output = `cmd`;
  ```
- To capture a command's STDERR and STDOUT together:

  ```
  $output = `cmd 2>&1`;
  ```
- To capture a command's STDERR but discard its STDOUT (ordering is important here):

  ```
  $output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
  ```
- To exchange a command's STDOUT and STDERR in order to capture the STDERR but leave its STDOUT to come out the old STDERR:

  ```
  $output = `cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`;
  ```
- To read both a command's STDOUT and its STDERR separately, it's easiest to redirect them separately to files, and then read from those files when the program is done:

  ```
  system("program args 1>program.stdout 2>program.stderr");
  ```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IPC::Open3) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IPC::Run). Also, read [How can I capture STDERR from an external command](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f) from [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html).

Comment: It'd be great to have an example here. You can use my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461472/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-and-capture-its-output-in-perl#comment93128903_2461530) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Beware about the answer of Eugene (can't comment on his answer), just above, that the syntax to exchange SDTOUT and STDERR is valid on Unixes (Unixen-like shells such as ksh, or bash I guess) but not under Windows CMD (error: `3>& was unexpected at this time.`).

The appropriate syntax under Windows CMD and Perl on Windows is:

```
perl -e "$r=qx{nslookup 255.255.255.255 2>&1 1>&3 3>&2};
```

Note that the command:

```
nslookup 255.255.255.255
```

will produce (something like) on STDOUT:

```
Server:  mymodem.lan
Address:  fd37:c01e:a880::1
```

and on STDERR:

```
*** mymodem.lan can't find 255.255.255.255: Non-existent domain
```

You can test that this syntax works with the following CMD/Perl syntax:

First:

```
perl -e "$r=qx{nslookup 255.255.255.255 2>&1 1>&3 3>&2}; $r=~s/[\n\r]//eg; print qq{on STDOUT qx result=[$r]};"
```

you get: `Server:  mymodem.lan
Address:  fd37:c01e:a880::1
on STDOUT qx result=[*** mymodem.lan can't find 255.255.255.255: Non-existent domain]`

Then

```
perl -e "$r=qx{nslookup 255.255.255.255 2>&1 1>&3 3>&2}; $r=~s/[\n\r]//eg; print STDOUT qq{on STDOUT qx result=[$r]};" 2>&1 1>NUL:
```

you get: `Server:  mymodem.lan
Address:  fd37:c01e:a880::1`

QED [fr:CQFD]

Note that it is not possible to get BOTH stderr and stdout as returned string for a qx or backticks command. If you know for sure that the err text returned by your spawned command is of length N lines, you can still redirect STDERR to STDOUT like describe by Eugene and others but capture your qx returned text in an array instead of as scalar string. The STDERR flow will be returned into the array **before** the STDOUT so that the N first lines of your array are the SDTERR lines. Like:

```
@r=qx{nslookup 255.255.255.255 2>&1};
$r[0] is "*** mymodem.lan can't find 255.255.255.255: Non-existent domain"
```

But of course you must be sure that there ***is*** an err text on STDERR and of strictly N lines (stored in `@r[0..N-1]`). If not, the only solution is using temp files as described above.

Comment: It may be better to close stream 3 afterwards with `3>nul` (haven't tested, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273866/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-only-stderr-to-stdout-not-combine-the-two-so-it-can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299317/io-redirection-swapping-stdout-and-stderr )

Comment: Tested redirection 1,2,3 under Windows (7/64SP1 and 10/64) with Perl qx{}: no side effect noticed after multiple qx in the same Perl script, while NOT "closing" stream 3. Strawberry Perl. I guess, either CMD or Perl restores descriptors when it terminates the fork/spawn. The example provided in the stackoverflow link deals with Unix shell and remains in the same process. I guess that should be the origin of different behaviours.