# How do you run an external command in perl while controlling its locale?

Tags: perl, locale

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461472/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-and-capture-its-output-in-perl) but more in-depth.  I am running a command like the following:

```
foreach $dir (@dirs) {
    $cnt = `svn st $dir | wc -l`;
    if($cnt > 0){
        $content .= "$dir\n";
        $mods++;
    }
}
```

However the directory contains non-ASCII files and thus throws an error when the locale is incorrect or not set.

The correct way to set the locale I need in perl is

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

However, this does not seem to be affecting the `svn st` command, as the locale error still occurs when the perl script is not run in a terminal with the correct locale set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable for the external command:

```
$cnt = `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 svn st $dir | wc -l`;
```

You could also change the environment of the script (`%ENV`), which changes the environment for any child processes:

```
$ENV{LC_CTYPE} = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 3):

Setup the environment for new processes by manipulating the `%ENV` hash.

```
$ENV{LC_CTYPE} = 'en_US.UTF-8';
$cnt = `svn ...`;
```