# redirect stderr and keep stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I want to write a `bash` script which should call several `python` scripts.
Within the `python` scripts are several print messages which I am not allowed to change. I want to parse the final status of the calculation to my bash script to decide what to do next.
My plan was to build the `python` file like:

```py
import sys

print('this is just some print messages within the script')
print('this is just some print messages within the script')

sys.stderr.write('0 or 1 for error or sucessfull')
```

and redirect the `stderr` in the bash script (but still keep the output of the `print` function on the terminal)

```sh
errormessage="$(python pyscript.py command_for_redirecting_stderr_only)"
```

can someone help me with only redirecting the `stderr`? All solutions I found will not keep the output of the `print` functions (mostly people set `stdout` to null).

And: If someone has a smarter (and stable) idea to hand over the result of the calculation, it would be very appreciated.

**Expected Output:**

pyscript.py

```py
import sys
print('this is just some print messages within the script')
print('this is just some print messages within the script')
sys.stderr.write('0 or 1 for error or sucessfull')
```

bashscript.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
LINE="+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
errormessage="$(python pyscript.py command_for_redirecting_stderr_only)"
echo $LINE
echo "Error variable is ${errormessage}"
```

output when I call `bash bashscript.sh`:

```
this is just some print messages within the script
this is just some print messages within the script
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
Error variable is 0/1
```

Comment: Maybe I am overseeing something but they in that proposed answer there is exactly that case missing when you want redirect stderr into a variable and keep stdout on the terminal

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299317/io-redirection-swapping-stdout-and-stderr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap stderr and stdout and store the stderr in a variable which you can echo at the end of your script.
So try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
line="+++++++++++++++++++++++++"
python pyscript.py 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | read errormessage
echo "$line"
echo "Error variable is ${errormessage}"
```

This should print your stdout as normal and print stderr at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately the variable $errormessage is empty when I run the script.

Comment: Sorry, you have to remove the parentheses around (python pyscript.py 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3), my bad

Comment: Somehow Its still empty... but errormessage=$(python pyscript.py 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3) works... thanks a lot

Comment: `read` at the end of a pipe may run in a subshell. This is a FAQ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763942/why-piping-input-to-read-only-works-when-fed-into-while-read-construct