# How can I redirect stderr to stdout but keep printing on stderr?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Is there a way I can "redirect" stderr to stdout but continue to print stderr?

I can redirect stderr to stdout with

```
cmd 2>&1 | other_cmd
```

However, the above will no longer print the stderr from `cmd` onto my terminal. I would like to redirect it *and* see the logs on my terminal.

Note: I do NOT want to redirect to a file, therefore I don't think `tee` works for me.

---

Edit: it was pointed out that this is similar to [How do I write standard error to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-standard-error-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)

I would say that this is a simpler subset of that problem. Though they are similar, I think this question stands on its own due to the fact that most folks (me included) do not understand the intricacies of process substitution and file redirection. In particular, folks would have some difficulty with converting:

```
command > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)
```

Into the answer given here

```
cmd 2> >(tee /dev/tty) | other_cmd
```

Among other things, that answer does not use `/dev/tty`, which I did not know you could do!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect stderr and keep stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431202/redirect-stderr-and-keep-stdout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash

```
cmd 2> >(tee /dev/tty) | other_cmd
```

In any shell

```
{ { cmd 2>&1 >&3;} | tee /dev/tty;} 3>&1 | other_cmd
```