# Unzip in perl ( to check file in this )

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract a ZIP file in Perl.
In my script, i can detect a ZIP file, i can select this .zip but after ?

```
    elsif ( $$file{'ccname'} =~ /(\.zip)$/x )
    {
        # Extraction ZIP
        my $zip_path=
```

Could you help me ?

Regards,

Comment: Use [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.45/lib/Archive/Zip.pm)

Comment: Use external command execute - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461472/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-and-capture-its-output-in-perl

Comment: @KostiaShiian: Why using external command?

Comment: @JE SUIS CHARLIE: Why not? We can run external program over system call like: my $res = system($7zpath,"a",$arc_file_path,$directory_path) and control result execution using $res variable.

Comment: @KostiaShiian: Because it's better to use a module like Archive::Zip.

Comment: @JE SUIS CHARLIE: I have just proposed an alternative solution

Comment: There are plenty of Perl modules that will do this. One `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` is a standard module. No need to use an external command that may work differently from system to system.

Answer (score 0):

The tool for this job is the [`Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.45/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) module.

```
my $somezip = Archive::Zip->new();
unless ( $somezip->read( 'someZip.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
}
```

and

```
my @members = $zip->members();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Extract;

my $extractor = Archive::Extract->new( archive => 'yourZippedfileName.zip' );
$extractor.extract;     #extract the files to the current working directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually just did this for a program I wrote. I used `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` which is a standard module in Perl. This took me a while to piece together. The explanation for `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` isn't the greatest, and it took a bit of trial and error.

These are the main points:

- You have to watch the exit status of the methods in `IO::Uncompress::Unzip`. If the status is less than zero, you have a problem. In that case, just `die`.
- There's an outer loop that pulls out the names of the `nextStream`. From here, you can get the `Name` of the stream which will be your file and directory name.
- Once you have the name, you have to build the path to the name. For example, if `Name` is `foo/bar/barfu/foobar.txt`, you need to make sure `foo/bar/barfu` exists, so you can write out `foobar.txt`
- There is an inner `while` loop to read from the stream's buffer and write to the file itself. This has to be a loop because it might take several attempts before you've read the whole stream. This is what took me a while to realize.
- I use `IO::File` which isn't necessary. I did this because everything else in this program was Object Oriented, and I figured it was time to try out the OO interface for file reading and writing. It adds nothing but confusion. Use `open` and `print` or `say` directly as you would in standard Perl.
- I use `File::Spec` to join together the directories and file names. It's officially the *correct* way to join together file and directory names. After all, you don't know if you have to run your program on a Vax or a Mac Plus running System 7. If you know you're only running on Windows, Linux, Unix, or Mac OS X, you can get away with `$directory/$file` instead of `File::Spec->join($directory, $file)`. Just don't blame me if your boss is upset that your script can't run on his PDP-11.

Here's an excerpt from my program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Basename qw(basename dirname);
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
use File::Spec;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile tempdir);
use IO::File;
use IO::Uncompress::Unzip;


sub update_zip { 
    my $old_zip_file = shift;
    my $old_version  = shift;
    my $new_version  = shift;

    my $zip_directory_name = dirname $old_zip_file;
    my $zip_file_name = basename $old_zip_file;
    my $unzip_directory = tempdir(
        "$old_zip_file.XXXX",
        DIR => $zip_directory_name,
    );
    #
    # Unzip Artifact
    #
    my $zip_fh = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new( $old_zip_file )
        or die qq(Cannot open zip "$old_zip_file" for reading.);
    #
    # Go through each element in Zip file
    #
    while ( my $status = $zip_fh->nextStream ) {
        if ( $status < 0 ) {
            die qq(Error in Zip: $IO::Uncompress::Unzip::UnzipError.);
        }
        my $element_name = $zip_fh->getHeaderInfo->{Name};
        next if $element_name =~ m{/$};      # Skip Directories
        my $element_dir = dirname $element_name;
        my $full_element_dir = File::Spec->join( $unzip_directory, $element_dir );
        my $full_element_name = File::Spec->join( $unzip_directory, $element_name );
        if ( not -d $full_element_dir ) {
            make_path $full_element_dir
                or die qq(Can't make directory "$full_element_dir".);
        }
        my $unzipped_fh = IO::File->new( $full_element_name, "w" )
            or die qq(Can't open file "$full_element_name" for writing: $!);
        my $buffer;
        while ( my $status = $zip_fh->read( $buffer ) ) {
            if ( $status < 0 ) {
                die qq(Error in Zip: $IO::Uncompress::Unzip::UnzipError.);
            }
            $unzipped_fh->write( $buffer );
        }
        $unzipped_fh->close;
    }
    $zip_fh->close;
}
```

Comment: This works great, except it reprocesses the last ZIP file entry over and over again in an infinite loop.  Suggest adding  "  && !$zip_fh->eof  "    to the while() condition.